# Groovy - Add Class to script via AST transformations

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree, dsl

I'm currently creating a `Groovy DSL` that looks like the this:

```
types {
   A "http://some.namespace.here"
   B "..."
}

testMethod(A a, B b) { ... }
```

The user defines several types and some methods on these types. What I need to do is to create `A` and `B` as `ClassNode`s in the AST so that Groovy can find them.

To do so, I created the following AST transformation:

```
@GroovyASTTransformation(phase = CompilePhase.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS)
class GenerateClassesTransformer implements ASTTransformation  {

    @Override
    public void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source) {

        ClassNode a = createClass("A")
        ClassNode b = createClass("b")

        ModuleNode module = sourceUnit.getAST()
        module.addClass(a)
        module.addClass(b)
        module.getClasses().each {
            println "class: " + it
        }

    }

    private ClassNode createClass(String className) {

        new AstBuilder().buildFromSpec {
            classNode(className, ClassNode.ACC_PUBLIC) {
                classNode Object
                interfaces { classNode GroovyObject }
                mixins { }
            }
        }.first()

    }

}
```

I then add the AST transformation to the Groovy shell:

```
CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration();
cc.setScriptBaseClass("groovy.util.DelegatingScript");
cc.addCompilationCustomizers(new ASTTransformationCustomizer(new GenerateClassesTransformer()));
GroovyShell sh = new GroovyShell(loader, binding, cc);
// ...
```

When I run the code and do NOT reference `A` and `B`, everything works out fine. However, as soon as I use `A` and `B`, Groovy cannot find the classes (although they are on the AST). Instead, I get:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\...\test.groovy: 23: unable to resolve class A
 @ line 23, column 6.
   A a = null
         ^
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Update: ClassLoader

I'm using a custom `URLClassLoader`, since I'm adding a couple of `JAR`s to the classpath:

```
URL[] urls = this.getExtraJarUrls(); // read JARs from a directory relative to the DSL script
ClassLoader base = Launcher.class.getClassLoader();
loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, base);
```

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way: which classloader are you using for your `GroovyShell`? And is it the same one you're using for your DSL execution?

Comment: @Keegan I updated my question. I'm using an `URLClassLoader` since I'm adding a couple of JARs to it. The ClassLoader has the current CL as parent.